# How to prove that there could be only finite or countable set of non-intersecting intervals in $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, infinity

Suppose we have $\{I_{\alpha}, \alpha \in \mathbf{A}\ - arbitrary\ set\ of\ indexes \}$ - a family of non-intersecting intervals, $ I_{\alpha} \subset [0,1]$. How to prove that its cardinality is not more than countable?

**UPD**: I concluded, that, in fact, there is a more common statement with quite the same proof as proposed in my own answer. Concretely,

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be a separable metric space, **B** = $\{B_{\alpha}, 
\alpha \in \mathbf{A}\}$ - family of open balls in this space. Than 
the cardinality of **B** is not more than countable.

As I stated, the proof is quite the same, but instead of $\mathbb{Q}$ one must consider constructing a map from **B** to **S**, where **S** is a countable dense set in $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: Euristically, every such interval will have length strictly greater than zero, and any uncountable sum of numbers strictly greater than zero gives infinity.

Comment: @ Daniel Robert-Nicoud, it doesn`t prove the statement. We can construct $\{t_1 = \frac{1}{n}, \dots, t_{n-1} = t_1 = \frac{n-1}{n}, t_n = 1\}$ and sum of lengths of these intervals will diverge as harmonic series.

Comment: In a more formal way, the number of such intervals with length $\geq 1/n$ is less then or equal to $n$. The countable union of finite sets is (at most) countable, so...

Comment: How many rationals are there?

Comment: $[t_1,t_2],[t_2,t_3],\ldots$ is by definition a countable sequence

Comment: @IlliaYurtsiv Daniel is claiming: "any uncountable sum of positive numbers diverges", while you claim "some countable sum of positive numbers diverges". Your claim, while true, in no way disproves Daniel's claim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just came to the proof. Each interval contains a rational number. So we can construct a map from the set of intervals to $\mathbb{Q}$. Intervals do not intersect, so this mapping is injective. So cardinality of the set of our intervals is the same as a cardinality of a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.